# Pip "install" Installs in Jython instead of python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, jython

I am trying to install "XLRD" library for python using PIP install, the library is installed successfully, after execution i tried to import the same but i get the error that no modules have been installed.

After some research i found that everything is getting installed in the C:jython/site-packages directory instead of C:/python27.

My pythonpath is set to C:/python27 , I checked.

What could be the issue? How do i instruct PIP to install modules in python directory.

Comment: what is the return of ``where pip`` in command line?

Comment: @loutre Wow, I typed the command and I got 2 responses, Its there in both pythion and jython directory , how do I make it default to c:/python

Comment: Look at your PATH env variable (``echo %PATH%``). Jython path should appear first. Swap Jython with Python path.

Comment: @loutre Yeah you are right, did it , thank you so much !! Appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your terminal/command prompt navigate to the Python home directory of the version for which you need to install the module. Then navigate into the scripts folder and run the pip command. Like below

```
cd C:/python27/Scripts
pip install XLRD
```

You basically need to point to the pip script for which you need to run this command. If thats for the pip script inside the python27, you need to navigate there or do like below as well

```
C:/python27/Scripts/pip install XLRD
```

If you have both the python27 & jython home directory & script paths in your 'PATH' environment variables, the path that was declared first takes precedence. To rearrange precedence, you would have to rearrange the order of the path declaration.

Comment: Wow , That absolutely worked, do you know why it defaults to jython folder?

Comment: It defaults to jython since you have the jython home directory & scripts directory in your 'PATH' environment variable.

Comment: I also have the same for python why doesnt it go there then?

Comment: You must have had the jython path coming before the python27 path. In that case, it takes precedence.

Comment: Ah.. I understand. Thank you !

Comment: I have added these points as well to my original answer. If that resolves the problem, please mark this as the answer.